# Add a git repo as a submodule but don't add its submodules

Tags: git

Is there any way to add a repo as a submodule, *without* adding its submodules recursively (even if `--recursive` is used)?

In other words if I have repo `bar` which contains submodule `bar/something`, then in repo `foo` when I do:

```
git submodule add .../bar.git
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then I do *not* want to get `something`.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible (without aliasing the git command or other weird hacks, which I assume is not what you want). This would need to be a config option in .gitmodules, but that does not seem to exist (https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules/2.32.0)